# How to turn off RTTI in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, rtti

I am not sure about other versions, but, in VS 2008 even with RTTI disabled I can query the information by calling `typeid(T).name()` on the type. It works with all types, internal and user created.

Our project has RTTI disabled but I was surprised to find that this still worked. Is this a Visual Studio bug or is the `/GR-` flag not enough to disable it? Does this fall into the realm of `undefined behavior`? If it is not a bug, how do I really turn it off?

Comment: Turning off RTTI is effectively _asking_ for non standard-compliant behaviour so whether what you are seeing is _undefined behavior_ is a meaningless question.

Comment: @Charles: "so whether what you are seeing is undefined behavior is a meaningless question" - ok

Comment: How did you check the results? Can you show some code? Maybe the type information could be deduced at compile time so in effect, it was not Run Time Type Info.

Comment: @Charles: Actually non standard-compliant behavior can still be well defined behavior when it for example behaves like defined by its API-reference and also standard-compliant behavior can still be undefined, as some behavior is explicitly defined by the standard as being undefined or implementation specific.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it possible that you used `typeid` on an expression whose type is known at compile time? If so you would bypass the "run-time" aspect of RTTI altogether. From the Microsoft documentation on `typeid`:

> If the expression is neither a pointer nor a reference to a base class
>   of the object, the result is a type_info reference representing the
>   static type of the expression. The static type of an expression refers
>   to the type of an expression as it is known at compile time. Execution
>   semantics are ignored when evaluating the static type of an
>   expression.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, using `typeid` (or `dynamic_cast`) when RTTI is disabled is definitely going to lead to undefined behavior.  My advice would be to not do that.

In any case, I don't believe it's the case that you need to do anything other than `/GR-` to disable RTTI in Microsoft's compiler.  It's perhaps a bug that it doesn't give a warning or error when doing so.  It does give a warning for `dynamic_cast`:

```
1>d:\src\MyClass.cpp (82) : warning C4541: 'dynamic_cast' used on polymorphic type 'MyClass' with /GR-; unpredictable behavior may result
```

However, it gives no such warning for `typeid`.  This hasn't changed in the VS2010 compiler either.

Side note:  gcc gives a compile error if you try to use `typeid` with `-fno-rtti`, while clang does not (even with `-Wall`).