# Why is this dynamic_cast<T> not working?

Tags: c++, direct2d

This should be quite simple.  ID2D1LinearGradientBrush derives from ID2D1Brush with a valid vtable.  I realize QueryInterface would work here, however my question pertains to dynamic_cast.

```
[definition from d2d1.h]

interface DX_DECLARE_INTERFACE("2cd906ab-12e2-11dc-9fed-001143a055f9") 
ID2D1LinearGradientBrush  : public ID2D1Brush
{
    // ....
}
```

However, given the over-simplified example functions ...

```
bool ClampToItem(ID2D1Brush *brush, SizeF itemSize)
{
    // As expected, works when a linear gradient brush is the parameter.
    ID2D1LinearGradientBrush *linearGradientBrush = static_cast<ID2D1LinearGradientBrush *>(brush);
    linearGradientBrush->SetStartPoint(D2D1_POINT_2F{ itemSize.Width, 0.0f });
    linearGradientBrush->SetEndPoint(D2D1_POINT_2F{ itemSize.Width, itemSize.Height });
    return true;
}

bool ClampToItem2(ID2D1Brush *brush, SizeF itemSize)
{
    // this dynamic cast FAILS EVERY TIME with an access violation
    ID2D1LinearGradientBrush *linearGradientBrush = dynamic_cast<ID2D1LinearGradientBrush *>(brush);
    if (!linearGradientBrush)  // <-- never gets here
        return false;

    linearGradientBrush->SetStartPoint(D2D1_POINT_2F{ itemSize.Width, 0.0f });
    linearGradientBrush->SetEndPoint(D2D1_POINT_2F{ itemSize.Width, itemSize.Height });
    return true;
}
```

Since I will not be certain that a ID2D1LinearGradientBrush will be provided as a parameter, I would like to use a dynamic_cast.  I must be missing something simple.  Do these COM objects not contain RTTI info?  Thank you for your help.

```
// For clarification, this works as expected
bool ClampToItem3(ID2D1Brush *brush, SizeF itemSize)
{
    ID2D1LinearGradientBrush *linearGradientBrush;
    HRESULT hr = brush->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID2D1LinearGradientBrush), (void **)&linearGradientBrush);
    if (hr == S_OK)
    {
        linearGradientBrush->SetStartPoint(D2D1_POINT_2F{ itemSize.Width, 0.0f });
        linearGradientBrush->SetEndPoint(D2D1_POINT_2F{ itemSize.Width, itemSize.Height });
        linearGradientBrush->Release();
        linearGradientBrush = nullptr;
    }
    return true;
}
```

EDIT:

Tracing into the dynamic cast (into rtti.cpp):

```
extern "C" PVOID __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL __RTDynamicCast(
    PVOID inptr,            // Pointer to polymorphic object
    LONG VfDelta,           // Offset of vfptr in object
    PVOID SrcType,          // Static type of object pointed to by inptr
    PVOID TargetType,       // Desired result of cast
    BOOL isReference)       // TRUE if input is reference, FALSE if input is ptr
    throw(...)
```

is called, inptr is valid, vfDelta is 0, SrcType and TargetType look great, isRef says false.
Tracing further, the memory access violation occurs here:

```
// Ptr to CompleteObjectLocator should be stored at vfptr[-1]
_RTTICompleteObjectLocator *pCompleteLocator =
    (_RTTICompleteObjectLocator *) ((*((void***)inptr))[-1]);

char *pCompleteObject = (char *)inptr - COL_OFFSET(*pCompleteLocator);
```

since *pCompleteLocator was moved to an invalid location.

Comment: Can you provide the error?

Comment: @awesomeyi I bet `ClampToItem2` returns `false` ...

Comment: ClampToItem2 will not return false.  I will edit the question to clarify the exception.

Comment: If these are COM interfaces, you're doing it wrong. You should use `QueryInterface`.

Comment: certainly I can use QueryInterface, but why am I unable to use dynamic_cast?

Comment: RTTI involve both your codebase and your compiler, first check that your compiler has RTTI enabled http://stackoverflow.com/a/6866868/2485710 , you can even possibly experience some undefined behaviour .

Comment: @Jeff It isn't a question of "*can* use QueryInterface"; You *have to*. `ID2D1Brush` inherits from `ID2D1Resource`, which inherits from `IUnknown`. Those are the only interfaces who's members you can hit without a query, and they wouldn't need dynamic_cast in the first place. You're assuming the underlying object is written in C++. COM is **not** C++.

Comment: @user2485710 - Thanks.  I use RTTI and dynamic_cast in other areas of the same project (VS2013).  I was just surprised when these Direct2D objects worked differently.

Comment: The book "Essential COM" has an explain regards this, COM wants to replace the C++ RTTI, it is different.

Comment: @Matt - I have Don Box's book.  And have been using COM for quite a while.  I think WhozCraig makes a good point.

Comment: @WhozCraig - Great point.  However the very inheritance chain you point out insinuates C++.  Of course, one can build a vtable without C++, like early days of COM.  But that isn't the case here.

Comment: Yup. C++ != COM, and COM != C++, but it sure is easier when you build COM *with* C++. You're absolutely right. The same vtable chain is constructible using C and a positively hideous set of legacy macros. If you've never coded a COM coclass with multiple interface exposures in C, consider yourself fortunate because it was a *pain*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Standard COM interfaces from Microsoft use [`__declspec(novtable)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k13k85ky.aspx) as part of their definition; if you look at the definition of `DX_DECLARE_INTERFACE` you'll see this is the case here. This means that the base interface classes don't have vtables, only the concrete implementation has one. RTTI doesn't have the necessary information for `dynamic_cast` to work properly.

For COM interfaces you should always use [`QueryInterface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do dynamic casting.

Comment: +1 Similarly, it equally can't be reliant to work even with non MS interfaces, and the easiest example where it falls on its face is a  marshaled interface pointer across a proxy-stub layer when moving between apartments. Generated Proxy/stub libs do lots of neato things behind the scenes, but RTTI provision isn't one of them. Bottom line: dance with the one you brought.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  That is what I was missing.  +1 and a checkmark!